# getting Error[Pe020]: identifier "" is undefined in IAR with an typedef enum

Tags: c, enums, undefined, typedef, iar

I haven't found any solution on internet and this is why I am asking here.

My Led_TypeDef variable is undefined in MyDriverConfig.h. First, I have definded in MyApplications.h:

```
/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MYAPPLICATIONS_H
#define __MYAPPLICATIONS_H


#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif


#include "main.h"

 typedef enum 
{
  LED1 = 0,
  LED_GREEN = LED1
} Led_TypeDef; 

#define LEDn                               1
#define LED1_PIN                           GPIO_PIN_0
#define LED1_GPIO_PORT                     GPIOB
#define LED1_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE()           __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()  
#define LED1_GPIO_CLK_DISABLE()          __GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE()

#define LEDx_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE(__INDEX__)   (((__INDEX__) == 0) ? LED1_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE() : 0)
#define LEDx_GPIO_CLK_DISABLE(__INDEX__)  (((__INDEX__) == 0) ? LED1_GPIO_CLK_DISABLE() : 0) 

void LED_On(Led_TypeDef Led);
void LED_Off(Led_TypeDef Led);
void LED_Toggle(Led_TypeDef Led); 

void MCU_Configuration(void);



#endif /* __MYAPPLICATIONS_H */
```

Then, in MyConfigDriver.h:

```
    /* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MYCONFIG_H
#define __MYCONFIG_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#include "main.h"



void SystemClock_Config(void);


void MX_LED_Init(Led_TypeDef Led);
void MX_CAN_Init(void);
void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);


#endif /* __MYCONFIG_H */
```

I thought it was well definded because my main.h included all:

```
/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MAIN_H
#define __MAIN_H

#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "MyDriverConfig.h"
#include "MyApplications.h"


#endif /* __MAIN_H */
```

These are errors I get:

```
MyApplications.c  
Error[Pe020]: identifier "Led_TypeDef" is undefined C:\Inc\MyDriverConfig.h 24 
Error while running C/C++ Compiler 
main.c  
Error[Pe020]: identifier "Led_TypeDef" is undefined C:\Inc\MyDriverConfig.h 24 
Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

Total number of errors: 2 
Total number of warnings: 0

When I include MyApplication.h in MyDriverConfig.h I get this:

```
Updating build tree... 
MyApplications.c  
Error[Pe020]: identifier "Led_TypeDef" is undefined C:\Users\Inc\MyDriverConfig.h 25 
Error while running C/C++ Compiler 
main.c  
MyDriverConfig.c  
Total number of errors: 1 
Total number of warnings: 0
```

I don't understand why I have two errors when I am not including MyApplications while I use Led_TypDef once in MyDriverConfig.h.

I also have tried to add 
    extern Led_TypeDef Led; 
in MyApplication.h without any results.

Comment: Get your headers right. You have circular includes - yeah, the guards protect them, but that is not the right way.

Comment: Ok I guess so but could you explain which way is right? What I am doing wrong? 
Did you say circular includes meaning both MyApplications.h and MyDriverConfig.h include main.h? Because it is the way used by STmicroelectronics SW examples.

Comment: Circular: A -> B -> C -> A (for example). Who says the ST examples are quality code? (I have a very private thought about that). My general recommendation: do not use this stuff, but program the hardware yourself. That is not more difficult in the final sum. Note: "MyDriverConfig" <-> "MyConfigDriver"??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you. For people who could be interested this way is working well:

```
    /* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MAIN_H
#define __MAIN_H



#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "MyDriverConfig.h"
#include "MyApplications.h"



#endif /* __MAIN_H */
```

Now in MyDriverConfig.h

```
    /* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __MYCONFIG_H
#define __MYCONFIG_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"
#include "MyApplications.h"

extern GPIO_TypeDef*  LED_PORT[LEDn];
extern const uint16_t LED_PIN[LEDn];
[...]

void MX_LED_Init(Led_TypeDef Led);


#endif /* __MYCONFIG_H */
```

Then, in MyDriverConfig.c

```
        /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "MyDriverConfig.h"

    [...]
    void MX_LED_Init(Led_TypeDef Led)
    {
   [...]
    }
```

Then, In MyApplications.h

```
#ifndef __MYAPPLICATIONS_H
#define __MYAPPLICATIONS_H




#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif

#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"




 typedef enum 
{
  LED1 = 0,
  LED_GREEN = LED1
} Led_TypeDef; 

[...]

void LED_On(Led_TypeDef Led);


#endif /* __MYAPPLICATIONS_H */
```

And finaly in MyApplications.c

```
    #include "MyApplications.h"
#include "MyDriverConfig.h"

GPIO_TypeDef*  LED_PORT[LEDn] = {LED1_GPIO_PORT};
const uint16_t LED_PIN[LEDn] = {LED1_PIN};
```

Code is not perfect because there are still some circular includes : stm32f0xx_hal.h but it is compiling well.